# transition functions and their order of operation

Tags: css, transform, css-transforms

I'm trying to understand how the transform property works with order of operation and its relevance to the transform duration.

Say I have some html

```
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li id="obj-1"><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li id="obj-2"><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The relevant css for `container` would be:

```
transition: all 6s ease 0s;
```

Now if I wanted to transform `#obj-1`, id write something like this:

```
#obj-1 {
    // some styling
}

#obj-1:hover {
    transform: scale(10) scale(2) scale(0.05); 
}
```

How would the browser interpret this css? My initial thought would be that it would allocate each "function" (3) an allocated amount of time (6s/3fun = 2 sec per fun). It doesn't work that way so I wanted to know if someone might point out what it is that determines how long each function would run or if they are somehow altered before execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your allocated amount of time for the animation actually depends on the **`transition-timing-function`**. Here you have given **`ease`** as a transition-timing-function. **`ease`** does not distribute time equally.

If you want your time equally distributed, you have to use **`transition-timing-function: linear`** for that.

See the example below you will see the difference.

> [***More help on Transition CSS***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions)

```css
.main div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.main:hover div {
  transform: translateX(200px);
}

.one {
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.two {
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

.three {
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

And your answer to **`transform: scale(10) scale(2) scale(0.05);`**

It will take the highest scale value i.e. 10, So your element will take the **`scale(10)`** as the transform.

> ***Note: If any scale contain 0 then scale(0) will take effect***

But other than `scale()` all transform values `translate`, `rotate` works differently.

**`translateX(100px) translateX(100px) translateX(100px)`** will result **`translateX(300px)`**

**`rotate(45deg) rotate(45deg)`** will result **`rotate(90deg)`**

See the example below

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto 8px;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

div.one:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg) rotate(45deg);
}

div.two:hover {
  transform: translateX(100px) translateX(100px);
}

div.three:hover {
  transform: scale(2) scale(1);
}

div.four:hover {
  transform: scale(0) scale(2);
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

And if you want to run these transfomm values in order I prefer to use

> ***[@keyframes CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40keyframes)***

Comment: Thank you! I overlooked the ease in the transition. Can I just add a follow-up question? Say my transform looks like this: scale(-4) scale(4) scale(0.001). In what order should it be executed? L-R, R-L or some other way?

Comment: @StrahinjaAjvaz I was wrong about the scale() add value. I did some practical on it and made a snippet above(second one). I think this will help you to understand the transform

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to write this up! You cleared up a lot of confusion I was having!